# Enable ListBox's ScrollBar even when the ListBox is Disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox full of (predefined) items with multiselect enabled, to prevent human errors I've put a checkbox to lock the Listbox to don't be able to select any item while the checkbox is checked.

Well, what I would like to do is re-enable the ListBox vertical Scrollbar (it's a default control scrollbar) when the listbox is disabled, to let me see the item's that are selected if I want to see them, just to navigate up/down on the Listbox using the scrollbar, just that.

Is this possibly to do?

This is the ListBox, it only has a vertical scrollbar and not horizontal:

[image]

Comment: looks like your `ListBox` supports some editing feature? if not, why do you have to disable it? to prevent user from selecting some item? ...

Comment: @King King nope, it's a default Listbox, just some times I click by error on an item that really I won't select and I don't notice my fault until later. And this is simply a fad that I have to navigate over the listbox items using the scrollbar When the listbox is disabled (I think it's a nice feature). sorry for my English

Comment: it's still unclear on why you have to disable that listBox, we can always have some work-around, once being disabled, I think there is no way to enable **just** the scrollBars, at least the scrollBars appearance of disabled state is hard to turn to normal state.

Comment: @King King I thought of another workaround which maybe could be manage the mouseclick events instead of fully disable the control, but I failed to try that. I turn disabled the listbox to cancel clicking on any item, but I would like to be able to still using the scrollbar

Comment: Done my friend :), its a great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to prevent user from interacting with the listbox while still allow him to use the scrollbar, this should do the trick. I've made a custom ListBox which supports some feature to put the listBox into *readonly mode*:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        //WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201
        //WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100
        if (ReadOnly && (m.Msg == 0x201 || m.Msg == 0x100)) {
          Focus();//do this to allow mouse wheeling
          return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }        
}
```

**Usage**: You just need to set the `ReadOnly` property to `true`:

```
customListBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Note that it just prevents the left mouse down as well as left mouse click. If you need to prevent user from doing more things than that such as prevent right mouse down, you can catch and filter out the `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` message.